micro services do not register on service-registry running with docker-compose
I have two micro services

Gateway : port 8080
Service -registry (eureka) : port 8761

If I run the services separately on local , it works fine , and the service registers with the ruke service registry.

but when i run the services , with docker-compose , they run separately , it runs fine individually , but the gateway service does not register on the eureka service registry
following are the configurations files
Gateway service eureka configuration (applicaiton.yml)
spring:
 cloud:
   gateway:
     routes:
       - id: identity-service
         uri: lb://IDENTITY-SERVICE
         predicates:
           - Path=/auth/**

 application:
   name: SWIGGY-GATEWAY

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone : http://localhost:8761/eureka/

Eureka service registry config (applicaiton.yml)
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
server:
  port: 8761

docker-compose.yml to run the services
version: '3.1'

services:
  gateway:
    image: 'gateway:latest'
    build:
      context: ./swiggy-gateway
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: gateway
    networks:
      - test-network
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - eureka

  eureka:
    image: 'eureka:latest'
    build:
      context: ./swiggy-service-registry
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: eureka
    networks:
      - test-network
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"

networks:
  test-network:
    driver: bridge

I have tried the docker-compose with and without the network

I solved it by adding the eureka default zone as environment variable in services for each microservices
environment:
  SPRING_CLOUD_DISCOVERY_ENABLED: true
  EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE: http://eureka:8761/eureka/

